# Powershell: Copy JSON properties recursively

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to write a simple powershell script to get a list of keys/values in file1.json and update the values of those keys from file2.json

The problem I'm running into is those can be nested properties and I don't know the names of the keys. There could be any depth of nesting so potentially need a recursive function to iterate over and search for these?

I can loop over the PSCustomObject to get a list of keys but I'm struggling when it's coming to the nested portion of this. Any help would be great!

Using PS v5

Update: It will also need to add keys not found

Comment: Please edit the question and include some sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (Powershell v3+). The idea is to read both JSON files first, do the comparison in memory, and then export the 2nd (updated) JSON to file again.

```
# function to copy JSON properties from source to target
# obj1: source object
# obj2: target object
# (values will be copied,
# missing properties will be added,
# extra properties will be left untouched)
function Copy_Keys ($obj1, $obj2) {
    # loop properties of source object
    foreach ($property1 in $obj1.PSObject.Properties) {
        $key = $property1.Name
        $value1 = $property1.Value
        $property2 = $obj2.PSObject.Properties.Item($key)
        # check if property exists in target object
        if ($null -ne $property2) {
            $value2 = $property2.Value
            # if both values are objects: compare recursively
            if ($value1 -is [PSObject] -and $value2 -is [PSObject]) {
                Copy_Keys $value1 $value2
            }
            # else simply copy the value
            else {
                $obj2.$key = $value1
            }
        }
        # property does not exist: add it
        else {
             $obj2 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $key -Value $value1
        }
    }
}

# Read JSON from source(s)
$obj1 = Get-Content "file1.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$obj2 = Get-Content "file2.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

# Copy the properties
Copy_Keys $obj1 $obj2

# Update file2 by re-exporting the JSON
$obj2 | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "file2.json"
```

Comment: Hi Marsze, that's a nice way to loop over keys - much neater than my existing solution but how would I then update the keys in file2 based on the output of this?

Comment: that's awesome thank you so much! Saved me hours and hours!

Comment: @PaulEvans You should put the code of your existing solution into the original question. Glad this is working for you, let me know if there are any issues.